# Magento 2 - Email notifications have server path as 'from' email

Tags: magento2, order-email

When receiving email notifications from our Magento 2 site (order confirmations etc), the 'From' email header field includes the server path, as opposed to the Sales Representatives details.  The means that in some instances the email is being seen as junk.  So for example cpanelusername@servername.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do feel that, its sending an email with your local email server. I would suggest that, please do uses SMTP to send an email. You can use couple of free extension to send an email via SMTP.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Both extension provide support for most of the email service provider.

**Problem solved? Please give 'Kudos' and accept 'Answer as Solution'.**